# Decimal points to Hexadecimal Conversion in Verilog

Tags: hex, verilog

I am working on a verilog code. I am completely new to verilog.
Suppose, I have to represent 0.6072529350088814 in hexadecimal, its value comes out to be 32'h26dd3b6a, as shown in code on the below :
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/354594/cordic-algorithm-using-verilog

But I donot understand how this conversion works?

Suppose I want to display the value and see it in decimal, what should be code?

`timescale 1ns / 1ps

```
module top(

    );
    
    wire signed[31:0] init_value= 32'h26dd3b6a;  // 0.6072529350088814
    always@(*)
    begin
    
    
    $display("The init_value= %d", init_value);
    
    end
```

endmodule
I have tested the above line of code, but this does not work.
The value of the init_value is displayed as

```
The init_value=   652032874
```

I expect that result should be 0.6072529350088814.

Comment: Not sure how to do it by programming. Please provide some link.

Comment: I really do not understand how to do it even manually.

Comment: verilog does not understand nor operate floating point values (except real types in testbench). Verilog only understand bits. What those bits represent is up to you. Some printing formatting qualifiers, i.e. %d display bits as *characters* which represent decimal numbers. But whatever non-decimal representation you use, displaying it is your own function. Verilog does not know how to convert it to characters. So, you need to read and understand about conversion you use.

Comment: I am trying to make a cordic algorithm to produce sine and cos wave. After every iteration, the values are adjusted by addition and subtraction and finally a accurate waveform is produced. I am not able to debug  my errors between every iteration.

Comment: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/sp06/handout/fixedpt.html

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```SystemVerilog
$display("The init_value = %f", $itor(init_value) / (2 ** 30));
```

Prints:

```
The init_value = 0.607253
```

I am not sure if the code under the link is correct. Theoretically, the conversion should be done through `2 ** 31` or `2 ** 32`.